# How to Overclock a Dell Inspiron 531?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, dell-inspiron, overclocking

I have searched all over the web on how to overclock a Dell computer. I cant find anything about it. I am trying to overclock the CPU.

**My specs:**

**Mainboard** : Dell 0RY206

**Chipset** :   nVidia 6100V

**Processor** : AMD Athlon 64 X2 4400+ @ 2300 MHz

**Physical Memory** :   2048 MB (2 x 1024 DDR2-SDRAM )

**Video Card** :    NVIDIA GeForce 8300 GS

**Hard Disk** : ST332062 (320 GB)

**DVD-Rom Drive** : PBDS DVD+-RW DH-16W1S SCSI CdRom Device

**Monitor Type** :  Samsung SyncMaster - 24 inches

**Operating System** :  Windows 7 Ultimate Professional 6.01.7600

**DirectX** :   Version 10.00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't find anything because 99% of dells cannot be overclocked. They purposely disable this kind of capability in most of there machines and motherboards. I believe they only allow this kind of activity with some of their upper end XPS systems.  There are reports of people getting certain models overclocked, but not easily and it varies.

No, there is no official way to unlock the ability to overclock.

Here is a great website and forum topic to check out and read. Someone wrote up a good post about this exactly:

http://forums.extremeoverclocking.com/showthread.php?t=196767

Also, check out these questions from the this site:

[What is overclocking the system?](https://superuser.com/questions/25941/what-is-overclocking-the-system)

[What steps do you take when overclocking?](https://superuser.com/questions/17513/what-steps-do-you-take-when-overclocking)

Comment: Why not?

Comment: Side note: Why do you want to overclock? Even if you could, you wouldn't get much more out of this system besides more noise from the fans reving up from the heat increase. It doesn't look like your gaming much by that video card you are running.

Comment: Ah I see. :( I wanted my CPU to operate at 2.6 GHz but I guess that's not possible. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Added a link for you to check out and read. Also, that website is a great place to find any resources about overclocking if you want to attempt something. Good luck!

Comment: Read the whole thing. Thanks. I have been convinced! Best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I stumbled upon while trying to find the software that I used before to OC my 531. I have the x2 5000+ 2.6ghz AMD, and I had it running at 3ghz without issues. Can't remember what software I used, but at the moment I'm using nvidia performance tools and can get it right under 2.9ghz before crashing. I did however change my ram since the last OC, so that may be the problem.

Just wanted anyone else who finds themselves on this page to know that just because it's a Dell, doesn't mean you can't OC it.